# Running Cosmos DB Emulator in a docker container. UI completely unresponsive.

Tags: docker, emulation, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to run Cosmos DB emulator in a docker container. My OS is Windows 10.

I followed all the steps as explained by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator)

Eventually, after importing the certificate the Enulator generates etc. I do manage to have a container running, but the UI looks empty (see below):

[image: Cosmos DB "dead in the water UI"]

My understanding is that the UI should look like this instead:

[image: Cosmos DB "happy UI"]

This second UI is the one I can see running the emulator directly on my machine (no docker container involved)

Notice how the UI in the docker container says "Document DB", while the one running on my machine says "Cosmos DB". Not to mention the different layout (and the fact that the second one actually works)

What puzzles me is that I am certain this is the same installer we are looking at here. I know this because, after having this issue with the official Microsoft image, we build our own docker image using the same installer that put Cosmos DB Emulator on our machines and when we run it... same result.

To be clear - those 2 UIs are the result of the same installer, running in  docker container and running on a windows 10 machine.

Has anyone else encountered the same issue and if so, have you found a way to fix this issue?

All help highly appreciated

Comment: I forgot to add that Cosmos DB is actually working - provided I access it via the RESTful interface, but it won't accept requests via the .NET client

Comment: I'm seeing the same; The Docker image runs a very old version of the Cosmos DB Emulator MSI installer. It only gets updated when the docker image is built.

I tried building from the docker source on github, but didn't get it to update properly either, Though I don't usually use Docker so i might have messed up and it's worth a shot trying that.